# RNFS.upload gives unexpected end of stream error while I want to send files in the device to my server

Tags: react-native, document, react-native-fs

I am Using react-native-fs for sending the files I picked by react-native-document-picker.
so I make a function and call it when all the required files are selected like the code below.
[image]
and when I call the function `uploadImageReq()` I got the following error on console

```
ERROR Error: unexpected end of stream
    at Object.promiseMethodWrapper [as uploadFiles] (NativeModules.js:103)
    at Object.uploadFiles (FS.common.js:594)
    at uploadImageReq$ (AddScreen.js:73)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:45)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:274)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:97)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:45)
    at invoke (runtime.js:135)
    at runtime.js:170
    at tryCallTwo (core.js:45)
```

the files is

```
[{name: "imageFile", filename: "IMGs.jpg", filepath: "/data/user/0/com.bookland/cacheNONE/1201418716", filetype: "image/jpeg"},{name: "imageFile", filename: "IMGs.jpg", filepath: "/data/user/0/com.bookland/cacheNONE/1201418716", filetype: "image/jpeg"}]
```

**Thank you for your helps**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stringify all of your embeded items:

```
//Other code onTop
const {location, ...other} = payload;
form.append("location", JSON.stringify(location));
...
```

and i **strongly** Recommend you to use ***RNFetchBlob*** instead of Axios, dont forget to pass content type in to your header.

great coding